# perform condition on a text input

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, input

I have a text input, now I want to take that input, ask the condition of the nodeID[], and when matches assign value to [i]

ie... input = "1FA02C", var i = [3]

```
<script>
function myFunction()

{
    var myNode = document.getElementById('myNode').value;
    document.getElementById('enterNode').innerHTML = myNode;
}

</script>
<tr><input type="text" id="myNode" value="Enter Node">

<script>
var nodeID = new Array ();
nodeID[0] ="1FA01A"; 
nodeID[1] ="1FA01C"; 
nodeID[2] ="1FA02A"; 
nodeID[3] ="1FA02C"; 
nodeID[4] ="1FA03A"; 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below. I believe it does what you're looking for.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="myNode" value="" placeholder="Enter Node">

// JavaScript
var nodeID = [];
nodeID[0] = "1FA01A"; 
nodeID[1] = "1FA01C"; 
nodeID[2] = "1FA02A"; 
nodeID[3] = "1FA02C"; 
nodeID[4] = "1FA03A"; 

// The array above could be writen like this as well
// var nodeID = ["1FA01A", "1FA01C", "1FA02A", "1FA02C", "1FA03A"];

document.getElementById('myNode').onkeyup = function(){
  index = nodeID.indexOf(this.value);
  if(index != -1) this.value = index;  
};
```

[Working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tesuzakejojo/1/edit?html,js,output)